# How to escape characters in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a script to run a program that receives as an argument the name of a file. The problem I'm having is that the program doesn't work if the filename has special characters in it.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/a/1040843) post which helped me a bit. With a few modifications on that script I'm able to use the program with filenames containing `[` and `]`.

However, there are still some other special characters that cause the program to not run. Is it possible to create a batch for all special characters? If not, I would at least need to be able to parse not only `[` and `]`, but `'` as well.

This is what I have working at the moment. How can I at least add `'` to this?

```
if not exist "mp4\" mkdir mp4
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.mkv) do (
  set _a=%%~nf
  set _c=%%f
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set _b=!_a:[=\[!
  set _name=!_b:]=\]!
  set _d=!_c:[=\[!
  set _fullname=!_d:]=\]!
  "SOMEPATH\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%f" -vf subtitles="!_name!.mkv:si=1" -c:v h264_qsv -c:a copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -q:v 6 -look_ahead 0 "mp4/%%~nf.mp4"
  endlocal
)
endlocal
pause
```

If you could explain the reasoning behind stuff that would be cool as well. I don't understand much about scripting, but I would like to understand what's going on in this batch...

Oh, and [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Quoting-and-escaping) is the documentation for escaping characters in this program.

Comment: It looks to me like you did a `set _fullname`, and then never used `_fullname`.  Is that an unused value?

Comment: Yes it probably is. I copypasted the code from the post I linked, and only altered part of it. I clean it up once I get it working with ``'``